# How to compare(contains) Object[][] to string and add its values to another Object[][]

Tags: java

Okay pls help me out if you can.I tried searching this but couldn't find it.
So I got some Object and String

```
String s1 = "drug";
Object[][] objects = new Object[drgus.size()][3];
```

which is full...ex. {"AAA","drug","u1"}
now I want to compare this values with string s1 (possibly "contains")
and if this Object[][] contains this String s1("drug") I want to put this values in another Object[][]
Sorry for bad explanation if I explained it bad...Hopefully you will be able to help.

Comment: Your `objects` is 2d array, whereas in your example it is 1d array, I didn't understand the question

Comment: @javaguy I want to filter "objects" which has string "drug" in it , so another new Object would contain just objects with "drug" in it.

Comment: @javaguy if there is 
Object[][] objects ={"AAA","drug","u1"};
Object[][] objects ={"AAA","drugG","u2"};
Object[][] objects ={"AAA","somethingElse","u3"};
........new Object[][] objects2 whould have
Object[][] objects ={"AAA","drugG","u2"};
Object[][] objects ={"AAA","drug","u1"};

Comment: This smells like you need to create a class that contains three fields, and define `equals`, `hashCode`, and `compareTo` for the class. Then you could have a `List<MyClass>` instead of `Object[][]`. Then you can use foreach or closures to find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like this:

```
    Object[][] objects = { { "AAA", "drug", "u1" }, { "AAA", "drugG", "u2" }, { "AAA", "somethingElse", "u3" } };
    String filterString = "drug";
    int filterIndex = 1;
    List<Object[]> filteredList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    for (Object[] objectArray : objects) {
        String stringObject = (String) objectArray[filterIndex];
        if (stringObject.contains(filterString)) {
            filteredList.add(objectArray);
        }

    }

    Object[][] filteredObjects = filteredList.toArray(new Object[][] {});
```